# Using jquery append() in <head> (in a function/class)

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, append, head

I want to use the append() function from inside the `<head>`, in a function to be specific, like so:

```
function custom_img(src_img)
{
 $("div").append("<img src='"+src_img+"'>");
}
var myimg = new custom_img("test.jpg");
```

This is a quick example that I just wrote out. I want my function to make a new image like that every time I create a new object like this. Obviously this doesn't work, since the append() requires to be in the body (I've tried this).

How would I do this?

Comment: You can append things to the `head`, but I'm not understanding what you're trying to accomplish. You want to append an image to the head? Why?

Comment: I don't want to append an image into the head, I want to use the function to append to the div. Look at the source.

Comment: Yes, I looked at the source (code example), and the title and content. Your statement **Using jquery (‘append()’) in <head>** and **append() requires to be in the body** were confusing to me.

Comment: Excuse me, English isn't my first language and it might have been the fact that I might lack the required skill to actually ask this correctly, although it seems quite comprehensible to me.

Comment: @Anonymous: you should probably be putting your scripts directly before the closing body tag anyway.

Comment: Your english is fine. That's not what I intended to suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it's not working is because your div does not exist yet.
So you can either use the `$(document).ready()` function to wait for the document to load.

Or if you want the images to load together with the rest of the document, you could simply create a new div and insert the images there.

```
var div = $("div")
function custom_img(src) {
   div.append($("img").attr("src", src));
}
```

Then when the document is fully loaded, you can go through the array and insert the loaded images in the DOM.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#myDiv").append(div);
});
```

Comment: I am quite unsure what to do with this. I've tried putting this in a script in the head part, but there's still no result. Actually, the class is being multiple times in runtime, it keeps going. As it gets new info, it starts adding new images. Any further information you can spare?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using .after(), or even .html()

```
function custom_img(src_img)
{
 $("div").after("<img src='"+src_img+"'>");
}
var myimg = new custom_img("test.jpg");
```

or

```
function custom_img(src_img)
{
 $("div").html("<img src='"+src_img+"'>");
}
var myimg = new custom_img("test.jpg");
```